# Meteor.js / React.js App - how to add another user while you're logged in

Tags: meteor

How do I add another user while I'm logged in in a Meteor application. I want to give to an admin an ability to create users himself without logging out.

For login system I use accounts-password@1.3.2

If I use Accounts.createUser(user, function (e) { ... } then it logs out my admin and after a page refresh it logs in with a new user instead.

SOLVED:

Thanks to below answers I created

`Meteor.call('addingUser.insert', user);`

on the front where user is an object of values and then

```
'addEmployee.insert'(user) {
    Accounts.createUser(user);
  }
```

on the back end and a user was added successfully with an appropriately generated bcrypt password.

Answer (score 2):

If you create the user in a Meteor method (ie on the server, not the client), it will create the user in the backend, and not change the login status of the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that handles user creation (you could use accounts-password for this) in the server. Call that method in the client.

for more info about accounts-password refer to this: http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser

Let me know if this works or not. Thanks!